# Divide the values from a matrix by another matrix if the conditions are true

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, elementwise-operations

I have three data frames with values. They are related to each other and have the same column names but show different things.

```
dat1 = cbind(a = c(2,1,3),
                  b = c(2,2,3),
                  c = c(2,2,2))
     a b c
[1,] 2 2 2
[2,] 1 2 2
[3,] 3 3 2

dat2 = cbind(a = c(20, 20, 20),
                  b = c(30, 30, 30),
                  c = c(50, 50, 50))
     a  b  c
[1,] 20 30 50
[2,] 20 30 50
[3,] 20 30 50

dat3 = cbind("1" = c(100,100,100),
            "2" = c(200, 200, 200),
            "3" = c(300, 300, 300))

       1   2   3
[1,] 100 200 300
[2,] 100 200 300
[3,] 100 200 300
```

Ignore the pattern of the values in `dat2` and `dat3`. It is just for illustration. My data set has more random values.

to get `result`

```
         a     b    c
[1,] 0.100 0.150 0.25
[2,] 0.200 0.150 0.25
[3,] 0.067 0.067 0.25
```

which is basically

```
     1        2        3       
[1,] "20/200" "30/200" "50/200"
[2,] "20/100" "30/200" "50/200"
[3,] "20/300" "30/300" "50/200"
```

The rationale is that if the values in `dat1` has the value `1` then take the corresponding value from `dat2` and divide by the corresponding values and column in `dat3`. Similarly, if the values in `dat1` has the value `2` in `dat1`, then take the corresponding value from `dat2` (with the same "position") and divide by the corresponding value and column in `dat3`. The same goes for the values of `3`.

For example, let's look at `dat1` and values of `1`. We only have one data point with the value `1`, and it is `dat2[2,1]` with value `20`. Take `20` and divide by `dat3[2,1]`. Or look at `dat2[3,1]` with value `3` from `dat1`. Take `dat2[3,1]` (with value `20`) and divide by `300` in `dat3` because it is assigned value `3` in `dat1`.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is output from my data using `dput()` for `dat1` and `dat3` respectively.

```
structure(list(DNB = c(1, 1, 1), `NORSK HYDRO` = c(2, 2, 2), 
    ORKLA = c(1, 1, 1), STOREBRAND = c(1, 1, 2), ATEA = c(1, 
    1, 1), `SCHIBSTED A` = c(2, 2, 2), BONHEUR = c(1, 1, 1), 
    EKORNES = c(1, 1, 1), `KONGSBERG GRUPPEN` = c(2, 2, 2), `TOMRA SYSTEMS` = c(1, 
    1, 1), VEIDEKKE = c(1, 1, 2), `ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `OLAV THON EIEP.` = c(2, 2, 2), `PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK` = c(2, 2, 2), `STOLT-NIELSEN` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `ODFJELL 'A'` = c(1, 1, 1), `SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SPAREBANK 1 SMN` = c(2, 2, 2), `WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `NORDEA BANK (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `VOLVO 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `SANDVIK (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SEB 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 1), `SCA 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SSAB 'A' (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `VOLVO 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `DANSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 3), `CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `TDC (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `TOPDANMARK (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)` = c(3, 
    3, 2), `JYSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 1), `NKT (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `SYDBANK (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 1), `GN STORE NORD (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `ALK-ABELLO (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(3, 3, 2), `SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `NOKIA (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `SAMPO 'A' (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `KONE 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `WARTSILA (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `METSO (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `HUHTAMAKI (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `FINNAIR (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `KEMIRA (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `UPONOR (~NK)` = c(1, 1, 1), `KESKO 'B' (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 2), `ORION 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `RAISIO (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `TIETO OYJ (~NK)` = c(1, 
    1, 1), `METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `ORION 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 2, 2), `STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)` = c(2, 
    2, 2)), .Names = c("DNB", "NORSK HYDRO", "ORKLA", "STOREBRAND", 
"ATEA", "SCHIBSTED A", "BONHEUR", "EKORNES", "KONGSBERG GRUPPEN", 
"TOMRA SYSTEMS", "VEIDEKKE", "ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI", "OLAV THON EIEP.", 
"PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES", "SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK", "STOLT-NIELSEN", 
"ODFJELL 'A'", "SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE", "SPAREBANK 1 SMN", "WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'", 
"NORDEA BANK (~NK)", "ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)", "VOLVO 'B' (~NK)", 
"SANDVIK (~NK)", "SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)", 
"SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)", "HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)", "SEB 'A' (~NK)", 
"INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)", "SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)", "ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)", 
"SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)", "SCA 'B' (~NK)", "SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)", 
"HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)", "SSAB 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)", "INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)", 
"VOLVO 'A' (~NK)", "NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)", "DANSKE BANK (~NK)", 
"COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)", "A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)", 
"TDC (~NK)", "TOPDANMARK (~NK)", "WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)", 
"JYSKE BANK (~NK)", "KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)", "NKT (~NK)", 
"ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)", "SYDBANK (~NK)", "FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)", 
"GN STORE NORD (~NK)", "ALK-ABELLO (~NK)", "BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)", 
"SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)", "ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)", 
"NOKIA (~NK)", "SAMPO 'A' (~NK)", "KONE 'B' (~NK)", "UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)", 
"WARTSILA (~NK)", "METSO (~NK)", "STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)", "HUHTAMAKI (~NK)", 
"FINNAIR (~NK)", "KEMIRA (~NK)", "UPONOR (~NK)", "KESKO 'B' (~NK)", 
"ORION 'B' (~NK)", "OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)", "RAISIO (~NK)", "TIETO OYJ (~NK)", 
"METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)", "ORION 'A' (~NK)", "STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)", 
"STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")


structure(c(572008.53, 617720.24, 654277.81, 686839.49, 736058.9, 
714108.91, 8344.65, 9753.26, 5407.72), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3"), c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Here are the dimensions of the actual data.

`dat1` using `dim()` gives

```
[1] 252  80
```

`dat2` using `dim()` gives

```
[1] 252  80
```

`dat3` using `dim()` gives

```
[1] 252   3
```

Comment: Not clear what you need. Also how is `50 / 200` Inf?

Comment: @Sotos I added another example, but I am not sure if it helps. I corrected the error now regarding Inf.

Comment: You noticed that the values 20 are divided by 200,100 and 300, which refers back to `dat1`. `dat1[1,1]` has value 2 which means that it should be divided by the corresponding value in `dat3` (i.e. `dat3[2,1]` or 200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for something like this I believe:

YOu need to convert the dat1 and dat2 to matrix not data frames.

```
dat1 <- as.matrix(dat1) 
dat2 <- as.matrix(dat2)

dfx <- do.call('rbind', lapply(1:nrow(dat1),function(x)dat3[x,dat1[x,]]))
```

To recieve the ratio you need to divide dat2 by dfx(since no dat2 provided, I am leaving this for OP to solve):

```
dat2/dfx #This should give you final answer
```

**Output**:

```
> dat2/dfx
              a    b    c
[1,] 0.10000000 0.15 0.25
[2,] 0.20000000 0.15 0.25
[3,] 0.06666667 0.10 0.25
```

**Sample output**

```
> do.call('rbind', lapply(1:nrow(dat1),function(x)dat3[x,c(dat1[x,])]))
            1        2        1        1
[1,] 572008.5 686839.5 572008.5 572008.5
[2,] 617720.2 736058.9 617720.2 617720.2
[3,] 654277.8 714108.9 654277.8 714108.9
            1        2        1        1
[1,] 572008.5 686839.5 572008.5 572008.5
[2,] 617720.2 736058.9 617720.2 617720.2
[3,] 654277.8 714108.9 654277.8 654277.8
```

Comment: Seems like what I am looking for. However, how can I do it for my data set with length 80 for dat1?

Comment: I get a debug error message when I try using 1:80 with my data set with message "  invalid subscript type 'list'". Do you happen to know what might the issue be?

Comment: @Mataunited17    Copy and paste entire error, unable to tell without seeing i

Comment: Here it is:

Error in dat3[x, dat1[x, ]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Comment: @Mataunited17 so its seems your matrix is not uniform after all. You have to make a better example to cover your problem in detail. The error means that that given dimesion(s) is/are not matching

Comment: I've added output from my data set. I thought I made good examples reflecting my real data set. Thanks for the help btw. I have been struggling with this issue for a couple days now.@PKumar

Comment: @Mataunited17 hmmm, try adding dimrnsion info as welll in your question, like no of actual rows and cols in all the three matrix. It will give more perspective. O m hopeful that you will be able to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Just did! `dat1` and `dat2` have the same column names, and reflect values for the same variables, but `dat3` is the `rowSum` of `dat2` (for my data).

Comment: @Mataunited17, give me some time i will update my solution

Comment: It should be very to easy to do so in Excel, but much harder to do in R.

Comment: @Mataunited17 Updated the answer, No its easier in R :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are the best. This was creating so much headache for me. I can't thank you enough!!